# process completed but whynot print the result

Tags: java

I'm newbie in java. i just want to make a simple code can read array 2D like this.

```
74  85  123 1
73  84  122 1
72  83  121 1
```

i have the code like this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("src/haha.txt"));
        int rows = 0;
        int columns = 0;

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        ++rows;
        Scanner colReader = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
        while(colReader.hasNextInt())
        {
            ++columns;
        }
    }
    int[][] a = new int[rows][columns];

    input.close();

    // read in the data
    input = new Scanner(new File("src/haha.txt"));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {
                a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

when compile, is progress complete. but the code dont want print the result.
where is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: No need for ``import java.lang.*;``. This is already implied.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code has two errors I can see:

1. In the `while` loop you call `new Scanner(input.next())`. That should be `nextLine()`, not `next()`.
2. When the `while` loop completes, all `input` has been consumed, so any further `hasNextInt()` in the `for` loops will return false.

Solution: When you don't know the size of the input up front, you should load the data into `List` objects, not arrays. You can always convert to array afterwards, if using array is important.

Alternative: Close and re-open `input`.

---

Oh, that's another error:

3. You never close `input`. You should use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)s.

---

4. You have to actually call `nextInt()` inside the inner `while` loop to *consume* the value, otherwise it will never end.
   Since you don't actually care about the value, you can call `next()` instead to skip the integer parsing, but that is a very minor performance improvement, and calling `nextInt()` is more consistent with the `hasNextInt()` call.

Comment: i just update my code and try debuging. but in while(colReader.hasNextInt()) not stop. just loop. how to fix it?

Comment: @swatzz You have to call `nextInt()` inside the loop to actually *consume* the next value.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to show the mixed use of `List` to process input then convert to an `int[][]` after all input has been processed. In reality, if you are not required to convert to an `int[][]` then you could avoid the extra effort of converting from `List`.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class KNN {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("D:\\Data\\foundation\\src\\main\\resources\\haha.txt"));
            List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
            int maxColumns = 0;

            while(input.hasNextLine()){
                List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
                String rowStr = input.nextLine();
                final String[] split = rowStr.split(" ");

                for(String val: split){
                    val = val.trim();
                    if(val.length() > 0) {
                        row.add(Integer.valueOf(val));
                    }
                }
                matrix.add(row);
                maxColumns = (row.size() > maxColumns) ? maxColumns : row.size();
            }

            Integer[][] integerMatrix = new Integer[matrix.size()][maxColumns];
            for(int i = 0; i < integerMatrix.length; i++){
                Integer[] row = matrix.get(i).toArray( integerMatrix[i]);
                integerMatrix[i] = row;
                for(Integer col: row){
                    System.out.print(col + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            //Added just to show that the integerMatrix is fully populated.
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < integerMatrix.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < integerMatrix[i].length; j++){
                    System.out.print(integerMatrix[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to do some debugging? 
For example are you sure that ***rows* as well as *columns* is bigger than 0**? It seems to me like they are not hence the for-loops never execute. So maybe it is not your program but your inputfile that is broken?

Whenever I face this type of problem I just fill my code with *println()* and see where it goes wrong or go step by step with a debugger.

Cheers.

Comment: This is not a valid answer and should be added as a comment instead.

Comment: How is it not a valid answer? It actually addresses the question way more than your 'answer'. He wanted to know why his output is not printed. I suggested. You just did some great Java-magic and made the whole thing seem very complicated to a beginner. His way is an alright approach, so let him do it.